# Sequentially Channel Write Sends Corrupted Data in Java.NIO

Tags: java, serialization, nio

I have a Server that uses non blocking sockets, nio. Server works in a separate thread and there is another thread called Game. Game thread holds the server object and uses server.sendMessage, Server thread only reads the data. When I call sendMessage two times sequentially for 2 packets in a while loop, after a moment i get "java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 6B6574B4" error in client.

part of server code:

```
public void write(SelectionKey channelKey, byte[] buffer) {
    if (buffer != null) {
        int bytesWritten;
        try {
            SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) channelKey.channel();
            synchronized (channel) {
                bytesWritten = channel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer));
            }
            if (bytesWritten == -1) {
                resetKey(channelKey);
                disconnected(channelKey);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            resetKey(channelKey);
            disconnected(channelKey);
        }
    }
}

public void broadcast(byte[] buf, SelectionKey fr) {
    synchronized (clientList) {
        Iterator<SelectionKey> i = clientList.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            SelectionKey key = i.next();
            if (fr != key)
                write(key, buf);
        }
    }
}

public synchronized void sendMessage(Packets pk) {
    broadcast(pk.toByteArray(), null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess (from the small amount of code you have included) is that you are not delineating your messages at all.  even though you send 2 messages separately, the io layer may split/combine those in various ways such that the receiver gets part of one message attached to a previous message.  you should use some sort of "message" protocol to indicate to the receiver exactly how many bytes to consume so that it can correctly parse each incoming message (e.g. write the message byte length first, then the message bytes).

as a side note, the `write()` method is not guaranteed to write all the bytes in one call, so you should be handling the return value and writing the remaining bytes as necessary.

Comment: +1 for "looping", but you should have mention that looping is not literally `while(!allWritten) { write(lastPartOfBuf();}`, it is asynchronous operation chain.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `flip()` before writing, and `compact()` afterwards, and you need to stop assuming that one `write()` writes the entire buffer. It returns a value for a reason. You need to loop, or if you're in non-blocking mode you need to proceeds as follows:

1. Write.
2. If the write didn't complete fully, register the channel for OP_WRITE and return to the select loop.
3. When the channel becomes writable, try the write again, and if it still doesn't complete just keep looping.
4. Otherwise deregister OP_WRITE.